# PUT Request is 200 OK, But the Data in Table is Replaced by Null

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter, crud

i'm trying to build an *API for CRUD from Android Studio with Retrofit using CodeIgniter4*.

**The problem is**

> when the *PUT Request* (here I use it to update old data with new data), *PostMan Response says 200 OK and the log that appears also matches the success log that has been written in the code*, but when I try to check on the MySQL Database, form that should be replaced with new data, but what happens is that the form contains null.

**What do you think the problem is?**

Here is My Data ...

**Controller :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use App\Models\Modelmahasiswa;

class Mahasiswa extends ResourceController
{

// Start -  readData

    public function index()
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
        $data = $modelMhs ->findAll();
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => 'Yeay!, Data Loaded Successfully',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        return $this ->respond($response, 200);
    }
    
// End -  readData
    

// Start -  searchData

    public function show($cari = null)
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();

        $data = $modelMhs->orLike('mhsnobp', $cari)
        ->orLike('mhsnama', $cari)->get()->getResult();


    if (count($data)>1) {
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => 'Yeay!, Data Available >1',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];
        return $this ->respond($response, 200);

    } else if (count($data) == 1) {
        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => 'Yeay!, Data Available == 1',
            'totaldata' => count($data),
            'data' => $data,
        ];

        return $this ->respond($response, 200);
    } else {
        return $this->failNotFound('Ups!, '.$cari.' Not Found');
    }
    }

// End -  readData


    public function new()
    {
        //
    }


// Start - createData

    public function create()
    {
       $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
       $nobp = $this->request->getPost('mhsnobp');
       $nama = $this->request->getPost('mhsnama');
       $alamat = $this->request->getPost('mhsalamat');
       $prodi = $this->request->getPost('prodinama');
       $tgllahir = $this->request->getPost('mhstgllhr');

       $validation = \Config\Services::validation();

       $valid = $this->validate([
        'mhsnobp' => [
            'rules' => 'is_unique[mahasiswa.mhsnobp]',
            'label' => 'NOID',
            'errors' =>  [
                'is_unique' => 'Ups!, {field} Already Added'
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    
    if (!$valid) {
        $errors = $validation->getErrors();
        $response = [
            'status' => 404,
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $errors['mhsnobp']
        ];

        return $this->respond($response,404);
    } else {
        $modelMhs ->insert([
            'mhsnobp' => $nobp,
            'mhsnama' => $nama,
            'mhsalamat' => $alamat,
            'prodinama' => $prodi,
            'mhstgllhr' => $tgllahir,
           ]) ;
    
           $response = [
            'status' => 201,
            'error' => "false",
            'message' => 'Yeay!, Data Saved Successfully',
           
        ];
    
        return $this->respond($response, 201);  
    }
    
    }
    
// End - createData 


// Start - updateData

    public function update($nobp = null)
    {
       $model = new Modelmahasiswa();
       $data = [
        'mhsnama' => $this->request->getVar("mhsnama"),
        'mhsalamat' => $this->request->getVar("mhsalamat"),
        'prodinama' => $this->request->getVar("prodinama"),
        'mhstgllhr' => $this->request->getVar("mhstgllhr"),
       ];
       $model->update($nobp, $data);
       $response = [
        'status' => 200,
        'error' => null,
        'message' => "Yeay!, Data $nobp Updated Successfully",
       ];
       return $this->respond($response);
    }

// End - updateData
    
    
// Start - deleteData
   
    public function delete($nobp = null)
    {
        $modelMhs = new Modelmahasiswa();
        $cekData = $modelMhs->find($nobp);
        if($cekData) {

            $modelMhs->delete($nobp);
            $response = [
                'status' => 200,
                'error' => null,
                'message' => "Yeay!, Data Deleted Successfully",
            ];
            return $this->respondDeleted($response);

        }else {
            return $this->failNotFound('Not Found');
        }
    }
    
    
// End - deleteData


}
```

**Model :**

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;
class Modelmahasiswa extends Model
{
    protected $table            = 'mahasiswa';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'mhsnobp';
    protected $allowedFields    = ['mhsnobp', 'mhsnama', 'mhsalamat', 'prodinama', 'mhstgllhr'];

}
```

**MySQL Table Settings :**

[image: MySQL Table Settings]

**MySQL Table Before PUT/Update Data :**

[image]

**PostMan Get Data Response Before PUT/Update Data :**

[image]

**PostMan PUT/Update Data Response :**

[image]

**PostMan Get Data Response After PUT/Update Data :**

[image]

**MySQL Table After PUT/Update Data :**

[image]

**Thanks for your participation and your kindness :)**

I tried several times to change the settings in the MySQL Database Table Structure with the null value, because when I made a POST Request with the same Table Structure settings, the POST Request process ran smoothly, but it didn't have any effect to the PUT Request.

**After i change the null field**

[image]

**PostMan Response After i change the null field**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the database table structure make fields not null, if the controller tries to save a null value, the saving message will fail.
I think your problem is in the validation data.

Comment: I've tried to make the field non-null, but when the PUT Request data was sent to MySQL it doesn't exist